# Что означает понятие "Плоская таблица"?

Tags: база-данных, терминология

Встретилось вот такое описание:

> "остатки и цены на складе импортируется продолжительное время (remains.xml), создает нагрузку на БД так как хранит цены и остатки в node (по одной записи на каждую языковую версию node, но хватило бы одной записи на каждую товарную позицию). Требуется хранение в плоской MySQL таблице. Также импорт работал бы быстрее если бы XML файл обрабатывался через XMLReader вместо SimpleXML."

Что означает понятие "Плоская таблица" ?

Comment: Обычно под термином "плоская таблица" скрывается полностью денормализованный набор данных, т.е. "все данные - в одной таблице". Но что именно Вы и именно в этом вопросе имеете в виду - неизвестно.

Comment: Как то так   - "остатки и цены на складе  импортируется продолжительное время (remains.xml), создает нагрузку на БД так как хранит цены и остатки в node (по одной записи на каждую языковую версию node, но хватило бы одной записи на каждую товарную позицию). Требуется хранение в плоской MySQL таблице. Также импорт работал бы быстрее если бы XML файл обрабатывался через XMLReader вместо SimpleXML."

Comment: @Nikita - Вот такая правка к вопросу приемлима?

Answer (score 7):

Это означает, что эта таблица самодостаточна и в ней хранится вся информация об объекте. Не нужно делать в запросе никаких дополнительных джойнов. Достаточно сделать

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

и получить всю интересующую информацию.

Часто это денормализованная таблица или вьюха, которая инкапсулирует в себе все джойны к справочникам